# WidgetCenter not found in scope

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit

I'm building an iOS app for iOS 10+. The app builds fine in Debug configuration, but in Release fails to compile swift source code that references `WidgetCenter`.

It outputs the error `Cannot find WidgetCenter in scope` even though I'm importing `WidgetKit` and optionally embedding the framework.

```
import Foundation
import WidgetKit

class MyWidgetCenter: NSObject {

  @available(iOS 14, *)
  func reloadTimelines(_ kind: String) {
    // this line causes error: cannot find 'WidgetCenter' in scope
    WidgetCenter.shared.reloadTimelines(ofKind: kind)
  }
  
  @available(iOS 14, *)
  func reloadAllTimelines() {
    // this line causes error: cannot find 'WidgetCenter' in scope
    WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
  }
}
```

Edit:
It builds fine for the simulator and my connected device (iPhone XR) in Release configuration when I set the `Build Active Architecture Only` flag. It's only when it's building for multiple architectures that it fails to compile. Are there architecture restrictions for `WidgetKit` that I'm not accounting for?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe WidgetKit is supposed to support the `armv7` architecture, however it fails to compile usage of `WidgetCenter` for `armv7`.

My workaround is to wrap the `WidgetCenter` statements, to only support the architectures I need outside of `armv7`

```
class MyWidgetCenter: NSObject {

  @available(iOS 14, *)
  func reloadTimelines(_ kind: String) {
    #if arch(arm64) || arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)
    WidgetCenter.shared.reloadTimelines(ofKind: kind)
    #endif
  }
  
  @available(iOS 14, *)
  func reloadAllTimelines() {
    #if arch(arm64) || arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)
    WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
    #endif
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should first `import WidgetKit` in your file, and add the function `reloadAllWidget` below.

```
@objc public func reloadAllWidget() {

    #if arch(arm64) || arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)

    WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()

    #endif
}
```

When you want to update timeline, you use `self.reloadAllWidget()`

Comment: Are the new apple silicon chips arch(arm64) ?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I have to check only for `arm64`.

```
@available(iOS 14, *)
@objc public func reloadWidget() {
   // Compiler error fix. Arm64 - current 64-bit ARM CPU architecture,
   // as used since the iPhone 5S and later (6, 6S, SE and 7),
   // the iPad Air, Air 2 and Pro, with the A7 and later chips.
   #if arch(arm64)
   WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
   #endif
}
```

Comment: IIRC this won't work on the simulator, but it's been a while since i've ran the code in my accepted answer