# Cannot find type 'TimelineEntry' in scope while archiving

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, widget

I added IOS 14 Widget into my application. It works fine when test on simulator or real device. But when i try to make archive for app store, it throws error that "Cannot find type 'TimelineEntry' in scope".
Here is my code for timeline entry.

```
import Foundation
import WidgetKit

struct WidgetContent: TimelineEntry {
    var date: Date = Date()
    var lastVisibleIndexForDigitPicker: UInt64 = 00
    var isBulbOn: Bool = false
}
```

[image: I and here is screen shot]

Comment: I solved this problem by adding #if (arm64) before the structure.

Comment: refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63065117/widgetcenter-not-found-in-scope